# Error in sklearn : grid_ridge_m.cv_results_

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, scikit-multilearn

I am using scikit-learn version is 0.22.1. and I am getting error at grid_scores(0.18) and cv_results(0.18+) since I have sklearn 0.22 I used cv_result..

```
fig,ax= plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(12,5)
#df = pd.DataFrame(grid_ridge_m.grid_scores_)
df = pd.DataFrame(grid_ridge_m.cv_results_)
df["alpha"] = df["parameters"].apply(lambda x:x["alpha"])
df["rmsle"] = df["mean_validation_score"].apply(lambda x:-x)
sn.pointplot(data=df,x="alpha",y="rmsle",ax=ax)
```

### **ERROR :** when I am using (grid_ridge_m.cv_results_) I am getting below error

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2896             try:
-> 2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'parameters'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-69e67dace19f> in <module>
     17 #df = pd.DataFrame(grid_ridge_m.grid_scores_)
     18 df = pd.DataFrame(grid_ridge_m.cv_results_)
---> 19 df["alpha"] = df["parameters"].apply(lambda x:x["alpha"])
     20 df["rmsle"] = df["mean_validation_score"].apply(lambda x:-x)
     21 sn.pointplot(data=df,x="alpha",y="rmsle",ax=ax)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2993             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2994                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2995             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2996             if is_integer(indexer):
   2997                 indexer = [indexer]

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:
-> 2899                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2900         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2901         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'parameters'
```

Comment: Are you sure that your `df` contains the column `parameters`?

Comment: @DavideBrex (grid_scores_) generate different data table and (cv_results_) generate a different table, so my main intention here is to understand difference between 2 of them and an equivalent table fileds

Comment: To see the differences you can just print `grid_ridge_m.cv_results_` and `grid_ridge_m.grid_scores_` right?